# Managing jobs on remote computers running Windows

Tags: windows-xp, remote-desktop

I have 10 computers at work all of which have Windows XP (either 32- or 64-bit). Each installation is a separate one and not server-based. I work on different sets of code and to run jobs I have set up batch scripts for each which can take command line arguments.

Now to run any job, I login on the remote computer (via Remote Desktop) and execute it on the command line. I have no way to queue another process since if I overload the processors (i.e. jobs > processors) the run-time on each job takes a huge hit. The Remote Desktop approach is proving to be a huge bottleneck since that means the computers are sitting idle unless I login to check the progress etc. (which can be for long if, for example, I am working on some code development).

Can you suggest any software which will help me in this system? I have tried "psexec" but it does not work properly in the interactive mode. PlatformLSF is very very expensive. The only other software I think may meet my needs is Visualcron (plus its inexpensive) but not so sure about it. Any thoughts on Visualcron?

*I posted the same on superuser.com and was suggested that this might be a better platform to ask this question.  Also, I am not familiar with VBScript but am not averse to learning that but in the immediate future may be a software (free or otherwise) might best serve my needs.*

Comment: Why aren't you using Task Scheduler and then checking the Task Scheduler Log for success/fail? Do these commands need a GUI, and that's why Remote Desktop is used?

Comment: please don't double-post questions on multiple StackExchange sites. If your question is off-topic on the site you originally posted it on, it'll quickly get voted closed and moved to an appropriate site.

Comment: @ErikA, thanks for the pointer ... was not sure if that would happen.  Will keep that in mind in the future.

Comment: @ServerChecker: The commands are not GUI based are just scientific code executables.  I am using Remote Desktop to run my jobs as there is no other way I can specifically run a job on a particular machine.  I always assumed (incorrectly as you indicate) that Task Scheduler is very basic and cannot serve as a true queue manager.  Is it possible to queue jobs to run as and when processors are available?  Does implementing that require a script or the Scheduled Tasks interface is capable enough?

Answer (score 1):

I've used VisualCron several times before and it has worked perfectly. My usage was on Windows Server 200[3|8] machines, but I'd assume it would work equally as well on XP workstations.

Answer (score 0):

[Condor](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/condor/) supports Windows clients. Sun Grid Engine was a fine open source batch scheduler that could run on Windows, but the licensing terms are becoming onerous. You can take a look at [Univa's fork](http://www.univa.com/products/grid-engine.php) of SGE, but I think it wants Windows Vista or later. Both Condor and SGE have been widely used in the scientific computing community.